# Is there a Simulator for IAR?

Tags: simulator, cortex-m, iar, stm32f7

I'm searching for IAR Simulator where I can run my code without the hardware. If there is, is there a trail period? And also where can I download it and how do I simulate? The hardware I'm looking at is STM32F7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the EmbeddedWorkbench from IAR, you could simply debug your project and select the simulator as driver.

The EWARM has a build in simulator for the supported devices (but only the controller and no peripherals).

In the Project Options under Debugger you select *Simulator* as driver and than start debugging.

[image: Project Options]

There are two Demo Versions available (one with a time limitation of 30 days and a second one limited to 32kb code size)

You could find both on the [IAR Website](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/#!?architecture=Arm)

Comment: In the simulator section I cannot see the option probe to select. Is there something that I have to install additionally?

Comment: Small mistake, it is called driver.

Comment: Thank you. So now I can run the code without the hardware, right?

Comment: yes, but you have to observe some limitations (e.g. do not select the HSE since it will never be stable :) )